# Sentinel not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, sentinel

```
def load():    
    global name
    global count
    global shares
    global pp
    global sp
    global commission
    name=input("Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: ")
    count =0
    while name != '-999':
        count=count+1
        shares=int(input("Enter number of shares: "))
        pp=float(input("Enter purchase price: "))
        sp=float(input("Enter selling price: "))
        commission=float(input("Enter commission: "))
        calc()
        display()
        name=input("\nEnter stock name OR -999 to Quit: ")

def calc():
    global amount_paid
    global amount_sold
    global profit_loss
    global commission_paid_sale
    global commission_paid_purchase
    amount_paid=shares*pp
    commission_paid_purchase=amount_paid*commission
    amount_sold=shares*sp
    commission_paid_sale=amount_sold*commission
    profit_loss=(amount_sold - commission_paid_sale) -(amount_paid + commission_paid_purchase)

def display():
    print("\nStock Name:", name)
    print("Amount paid for the stock:       $",      format(amount_paid, '10,.2f'))
    print("Commission paid on the purchase: $", format(commission_paid_purchase, '10,.2f'))
    print("Amount the stock sold for:       $", format(amount_sold, '10,.2f'))
    print("Commission paid on the sale:     $", format(commission_paid_sale, '10,.2f'))
    print("Profit (or loss if negative):    $", format(profit_loss, '10,.2f'))

def main():
    load()
    calc()
    display()

main()
```

Sentinel "works" in the sense that it ends the program, but not without outputting the previous stock's data (that is erroneous). I would like the sentinel to immediately stop the program and kick to ">>>" after entering '-999'. Here is what the output looks like:

```
============= RESTART: C:\Users\ElsaTime\Desktop\answer2.py =============
Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: M$FT
Enter number of shares: 1000
Enter purchase price: 15
Enter selling price: 150
Enter commission: 0.03

Stock Name: M$FT
Amount paid for the stock:       $  15,000.00
Commission paid on the purchase: $     450.00
Amount the stock sold for:       $ 150,000.00
Commission paid on the sale:     $   4,500.00
Profit (or loss if negative):    $ 130,050.00

Enter stock name OR -999 to Quit: -999

Stock Name: -999
Amount paid for the stock:       $  15,000.00
Commission paid on the purchase: $     450.00
Amount the stock sold for:       $ 150,000.00
Commission paid on the sale:     $   4,500.00
Profit (or loss if negative):    $ 130,050.00
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `calc()` and `display()` from `main()`. You're already doing those things in `load()`.